# Schedule e-mail notification 24 hours before certain event?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I have a PHP-based site with bookings/appointments stored in a MySQL database.

I want to set an e-mail notification to be sent to each person who made a booking exactly 24 hours before their booking. Bookings are added through a regular PHP form.

I know I could add a script to, for instance, the index page that checks the database for any bookings that are in the final 24 hours, but that's unreliable since I won't be getting much traffic at first. So the index page could go hours without visits, and the notification would be hours late.

The other solution that came to mind is to set a cron job that runs every minute, calls a PHP script which checks whether any e-mails should be sent and sends them. But I'm not sure if this is overkill in a way; does anyone have a better solution than having something run in the background every minute?

To sum it up - is there a way to do this without cron?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use cron to set a very specific time and date to execute your script. Why not use that?

Comment: Because the user creates a booking through PHP, how could I dynamically add a cron job from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggering the job from a web page is a **very** bad idea, for two reason: (1) if you don't get traffic to your site, the job doesn't run; (2) if you get a lot of notifications, the job will be slowing down the response to the web requests (assuming you invoke the job synchronously).

I would strongly discourage you from running a job every minute either - it definitely will be an overkill.  Instead, think whether you really need "exactly 24 hours" as the interval or would "between 22 and 26 hours" be ok.

We have a similar requirements - and went about it by setting a job that runs every 4 hours and checks what notifications need to be sent for events starting between 22 and 26 hours form the time the script runs.  This way, the script is only execute 6 times in a day and everything gets sent correctly.

If 4 hours approximation is not good enough, then think to the largest interval that's appropriate.  I'm sure 1 hour should be sufficient.  Have a script run once an hour (from cron) and check for events starting between 23 and 24 hours from the time of the run.

Remember that once your email is sent, it doesn't end up in the recipient's inbox immediately: sometimes it takes a few seconds, but sometimes it may take an hour or even more - so an extra hour difference in your script won't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing, but the client asked for precision for whatever reason. I guess the answer is to convince him otherwise:)

Comment: @robert Try to explain to the client that the email is not a time-reliable means of communication.  If you send an email now, then the recipient may not receive it until a few hours later anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use cron as an interval'd timer. You can set a very specific date and time when you want your job done.

**[Here's an article on the subject](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)**

For instance:

```
0 0 18 5 * <php command here>
```

Will run every May 18th at midnight. That's more than enough time to clear it before the next iteration (next year).

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is adding a cron job manually for every booking a user creates an improvement over my idea?

Comment: @robert: That's said in the article I attached, you can modify cron jobs from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way other than setting cron or sending request to server through periodic calls...below is post similar to your question, you may get idea.

[Live redirect based on periodic server calls with JSON or AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872209/live-redirect-based-on-periodic-server-calls-with-json-or-ajax)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a cron job every minute has no sense  ! but you can do a cron job every hour because i think it doesn't meter a hour difference or 2 hours .  without cron it isn't any other way . it will take about 2 second (at max) to complete so it is worth